# Type juggling - Ressource to boolean

Tags: php, type-conversion

I stumbled upon this bit of code (written by someone else):

```
$result = do_stuff(); //returns false on failure, and mysql resource on success

return $result !== false;
```

If I get it right, it casts `$result` to a boolean and returns it.

How could we justify the use of `$result !== false` instead of `(bool)$result`? Is the former one more efficient?

Comment: I think `$result !== false` a little more readable than `(bool)$result`.

Comment: Because a resource isn't simply true or false, here the code is actively type checking for Boolean as well as a value of false

Comment: @MarkBaker From [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) `Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).` A resource is considered true while casting, right?

Comment: It's the difference between `tru-ish` and `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by justify. Casting to bool will probably, depending on the result of `do_stuff()`, do the same, but is in fact something else and implies something else as well.

Example:
If you have `0` as returnvalue, casting to bool will make your function return false, but `0 !== false` will return true. This is probably not a usecase you have here according to your comment, but it is implied.

So what you are saying here is "return false if `$result` is exactly `false`, otherwise always return true", while casting to bool will return false on any value of `$result` that is 'false-ish'.

My justification would be that this is clearer: you are implying that the result is either really `false`, or you actually consider it true.